# MySQL configuration: memory usage "dangerously high"?

Tags: mysql

I'm running CentOS with DirectAdmin on a dedicated server (quad core i7 with ~8Gb RAM) and I've encountered major issues with MySQL, on which more details can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/477064/tmp-was-1-8gb-removing-files-older-than-8-days-has-deleted-only-300mb-what).

I've just run a perl MySQL Tuner script from [this website](https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl), to try and determine what the problem is.

Sadly, the output doesn't make a lot of sense to me:

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.2.0 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
Please enter your MySQL administrative login: root
Please enter your MySQL administrative password:

-------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.20-log
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 236M (Tables: 686)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 226M (Tables: 199)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 312

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 18h 42m 34s (1M q [18.265 qps], 49K conn, TX: 3B, RX: 835M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 60% / 40%
[--] Total buffers: 528.0M global + 7.0M per thread (1500 max threads)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 10.8G (138% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (3/1M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 2% (37/1500)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 64.0M/74.1M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.9% (8M cached / 5K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 66.9% (529K cached / 792K selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 83513
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 42K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 5962
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 5% (5K on disk / 97K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (37 created / 49K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 42% (512 open / 1K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 10% (756/7K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (513K immediate / 513K locks)
[!!] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 226.7M/128.0M

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    query_cache_size (> 64M)
    join_buffer_size (> 2.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 226M)
```

Is the tuner suggesting that my MySQL installation requires more than 8Gb RAM?

The main website on my server gets ~30K unique visitors/week, but even then, surely MySQL isn't being hammered *that* hard?

The settings in my `my.cnf` are:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
bind-address=127.0.0.1
max_connections=1500
long_query_time=2
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql_slow.log
expire_logs_days=14
external-locking

open_files_limit=1536
key_buffer_size=64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=128M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=8M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
group_concat_max_len=16k
max_sort_length=16k
max_length_for_sort_data=16k
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=4M
query_cache_size=64M
innodb_thread_concurrency=16
thread_concurrency=16
thread_cache=128
thread_stack=1M
read_buffer_size=1M
join_buffer_size=2M
read_rnd_buffer_size=1M
table_cache=512
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256M
log-warnings

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
```

Does anyone have any advice as to how I can optimise my MySQL installation?

Comment: That does not look normal in my book. I wonder if there is a faulty application doing something like a wrong join on two tables creating a `MxN` sized result set.

Comment: Where can I start with diagnosing such a problem @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar?

Comment: Maybe something is in the `/var/log/mysql_slow.log` (though it only affects three queries, it says). Unless you can effort the space and time to turn on query logging and wade through a big logfile (usually a no-go on production systems) the next stop would be to look at the applications that use mysql and talk to the developers about the possibility of big memory consuming queries and which join-statemens they used.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use InnoDB it looks on the first glance that you are not using the RAM to get the DB humming. How about this:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G 
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
```